# How to link to a specific comment in Blogspot?

Tags: links, comments, blogger

I need to link to a specific comment in Blogspot. Say we have this blog:

```
http://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=27481991&postID=8840732060462210463
```

And I know the ID of the comment (`c2646478064900693854`), but if I use the ID to jump to that comment, it works for a milisecond then it goes back to the top again.

```
http://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=27481991&postID=8840732060462210463#c2646478064900693854
```

Is there a way to link to a specific comment in Blogspot that works?

Comment: I think it’s a browser issue what you are experiencing, because I just tried it in Safari and it works as expected—it stays at the comment.

Comment: Does the same in Firefox (jumps to start). But in IE works and redirects to the specific ID.

Comment: Also works as it should in Chrome (stays at the comment)